# The title of my wordpress post appear only half the font size in google custom search result

Tags: wordpress, google-custom-search

Recently I started writing a blog using Wordpress and added a google custom search in my post, every thing work fine except the search result doesn't shows full font size of my post title.
Is it my theme css that is producing this error or do I need to customize the Google custom search. Since I can't inset an image I'll provide a link for the image here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it think the error is in your css please add this css to the bottom of your head tag

```
<style>

.gsc-result .gs-title {
    height: 1.5em !important;
}
</style>
```

Hope this help